# How can I measure pack volume?

Tags: backpacks, diy

I've recently started making my own bike luggage (and am designing some accessory pouches to extend my lightest backpack).  To compare to what I can buy and have owned in the past, I'd like to measure the volume.

The simple frame bag I made can be approximated as a cuboid with rounded corners, giving me about 8l - but this will increase if stuffed as the cross-section will be more rounded.  The toptube bag, however, tapers in height and width, and has an arbitrary curve, while a tool pouch is an irregular pentagon from the side and tapers.

So I'd like an actual measurement.  These aren't fully waterproof, though made from waterproof fabric, so I can't pour water in (it would flow out at the seams and zips, and the openings aren't necessarily on top).  What can I use, that's cheap, easy to get out again (so not sand; anyway that's too heavy), and ideally not wasteful?

Comment: *These aren't **fully** waterproof*. But are they waterproof enough to get a reasonable estimate by quickly pouring in water from prepared containers holding a known quantity?

Comment: @WeatherVane not at the moment, if I seal the seams

Comment: If I understand your use-case correctly, you could pour measured volume of water into polythene bags and put them into the bag.

Comment: @WedaPashi if I could seal the bags - WeatherVane's balloons would seal well. Of course with water, the density is known so volume can easily be fine by weighing the difference

Comment: @Chris: Yes, balloons would seal well, however, balloons have their own shape and two such balloons would still leave air-gaps between them at some or the other sections. To be sure, you'll have to put balloons in place very carefully to minimize the gap between them. With polythene bags, that won't be a problem.

Comment: @WedaPashi balloons filled with water, and not massively,  are softer and stretchier than polythene bags and will deform better to fill the space.  Unless you meant a single bag per compartment, as in  user3067860's answer

Comment: @WedaPashi some readers seem to be picturing stretched balloons like when filled with air under pressure. That is not my intention at all. The whole point is that they are flabby and shape themselves to the space, with no interstices. Also, there is no need to weigh them: a known volume of water is used.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Agreed. I too was picturing a tightly filled balloon, but Chris's comment opened up a different perspective. So, yes, you were correct about using balloons rather than a polythene bag.

Comment: @WedaPashi thanks, I thought about using a polythene bag, but they usually have holes in them, and it might be awkward to expel any air and seal, *and* they don't stretch and mold like rubber does. I wish I had thought of the bin liner solution.

Comment: @WeatherVane I only patched together your answer and the other answer, your answer had the water and the other answer had the bin liner. Seeing them both side-by-side made it more obvious!

Answer (score 22):

1. Put a large trash bag (bin liner) into your bag. (Double bag it if you feel the need.)
2. Fill the trash bag with water, either using a measured container to fill it until you reach the top of your bag, or fill the bag first and then measure while or after you pour it out.
3. Use the water to water your plants, let the trash bag air dry and use it as a trash bag.

This will be considerably easier if you have someone to help you hold the bag upright while you fill it. Also, tipping the water out may be a bit heavy. But using a fluid will get you the best measurement, and liquid is easier to measure than gas.

Comment: But a gas is a fluid! :p

Comment: For a full size backpack I'd use something heavier duty like a rubble sack or survival bag, but this is simple and effective. Some of my more awkwardly shaped bags might be harder this way.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Fixed it.

Comment: Poor plants will drown.

Comment: You can do all this with packing peanuts instead of water.  Except your plants might not appreciate it

Comment: You can weigh the empty and full bag - that's likely easier and more precise than the volumetric way

Comment: Seconding @cbeleitesunhappywithSX comment weight is the easiest way to estimate volume here 1 litre = 1 kg of water (or close enough for this purpose).

Comment: @bob1 I agree, though it depends on having suitable scales.  My kitchen ones are max 5kg, and the bathroom ones were designed by someone really annoying - like most digital scales they settle and hold rather than reading continuously, so you have to be able to lift the bag off.  Not too much of a problem for my bike bags, but a bit harder for a trekking backpack that would weigh nearly as much as me when full (and I'm not sure the seams could take it)

Comment: @ChrisH: It's easy to use your bathroom scales! First weigh yourself, then don your backpack and weigh the two of you combined.

Comment: @ChrisH - TonyK's method is the one I use, especially for airline luggage requirements. True a trekking backpack is a bit harder, but the principle applies. Measure a  litre of "something" (rice, beans anything really) find out how much it weighs, then fill with that something and divide by the weight, subtracting the tare weight first.

Comment: @TonyK, yes, I do that all the time, but I don't fancy trying to put on a  40-75kg backpack full of water without spilling most of it or splitting the seams. Rice would be no better. Beanbag beans or pingpong balls would would be too light. The bark chippings suggested elsewhere would work nicely. For the smaller bags, rather than wearing or holding them, I'd use a tray or board on top of the scales

Comment: @ChrisH: there shouldn't be any problem in taking off the empty bags,right? So, you could weigh the empty (+ plastic bag lining) bags first and either tare on that or note down and take it off. Main difficulty I see is that you need a support for the bag that holds it and is completely on the scale.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX that's the difficulty I was describing for the big bags, but my bathroom scales auto-tare when you turn them on, then expect you to step on, then read shortly afterwards.  I haven't tried constantly adding weight as with a hosepipe.  They also throw an error if you try to tare them with too much weight, but I don't know how much is too much except that I am

Comment: @ChrisH: then it only remains to say "I'm sorry you have such a scale"...  (and for me to make a mental note for what "behaviour" to check when I get a new scale)

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX I know, the last 2 I've had have been like that and it's not generally specified in anything you can see without buying it

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the suggestions above, how about using dried beans or similar (e.g. chickpeas, kidney beans, etc)? Once you have successfully measured your pack, you can rinse them and cook with them.

Comment: +1 but I suspect that rice is easier/cheaper to buy in bulk and it has smaller grains

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD True. Smaller grains help with getting an accurate volume, but they are more likely to get stuck in corners and be a pain to clean up. Pick your poison...

Comment: I buy dried pulses in 2kg bags anyway, so this is quite reasonable.  With the selection I have, chickpeas would be the way to go.  Rice (and lentils) would get caught in the seams, and the smaller grains wouldn't be much help in assessing volume compared to chickpeas which are small enough and near enough spherical, so should pack reasonably repeatably.  It would take a long time to eat enough for a big pack, but for my smaller ones, this is an option. (also @0xFEE1DEAD)

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD Can you buy it at the 0xDEADBEEFCAFE?

Answer (score 5):

Buy some rubber party balloons and a funnel. Pour a measured amount (say 0.25 L) of water into each, such that they are not stretched very much, squeeze out any air, and tie off the neck. Pack them into the bag so they distort and nestle snugly. Handle carefully so as not to rupture. It might be easier to control the filling and tying if each balloon is stood in a plastic tub, such that there is a loose fit after the water is poured.

To be clear: the balloons would not be tightly filled with water as they would be with air. They are filled only enough so they remain flabby, and so that the rubber can stretch and their shape can mold to whatever they are next to, or into a square corner, such that there is *no air* between any of the balloons, or the walls/corners of the bag.

Comment: Water balloons aren't actually that great at filling. The tension needed to keep it "balloon" shaped keeps it..balloon shaped....so it is closer to sphere packing.

Comment: @user3067860 the point is, *not* to have the rubber under much tension, so that they are *not* sphere-shaped. They are not strong enough use in the same way as if filled with air. The idea is so that they will 'pack' without any interstices.

Comment: You could also use ziploc bags full of water to much the same effect, and I would expect them to pack more densely than the balloons might.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert please see my edit and other comments about the (lack of) inflation or rigidity. Polythene doesn't stretch much, and IMO some rubber bladders will pack better. The balloons are used as bladders.

Answer (score 4):

**Pine bark mulch is a pretty good substance for your purposes.**
A bag of dry mulch is inexpensive (less than three dollars for a 2 cubic foot (57 L), 40 pound (18 kg) bag on Amazon) or you can get it at any garden center.  Also, you probably have a friend or a friend of a friend who could use it after the experiment.

**Addendum:**  A bag of dry mulch weighs about 40 pounds (18 kg) and is two cubic feet (57 liters).  Bagged **pine bark** mulch is easy to pour, dry (assuming the bag is intact), clean, and not dusty. (Shredded hardwood bark mulch does not pour easily.) You may want to swab out the inside of your bag after you have poured the mulch out, but that goes quickly.

Comment: A bag of mulch is usually 2 cubic feet. Two cubic yards of mulch is 54 cubic feet, and would weigh 1000 lbs or more!

Comment: @Nuclear Hoagie Thanks, and corrected.

Comment: You can line your backpack with a trashbag and dump the mulch into that instead of directly into the backpack, and then pull it out avoiding most of the mess inside.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight I've stolen your comment a bit and made it an answer--except skip the mulch and just use water.

Comment: But it is compressible, which makes it not ideal to measure volume.

Comment: @Ant if absolute precision was required that may be an issue, but to get a value comparable in accuracy to backpack manufacturers it's probably OK